# Populate an array using reshape2

Tags: arrays, r, reshape2

I have a `data.table` object of dimension 421,570 x 16 which stores data for multiple stores. Stores can have different department. This is only a made up example. The dataset is bigger.

```
> head(raw.df)
   Store Type StoreSize Dept       Date Weekly_Sales
1:     1    A    151315    1 2010-02-05        24925
2:     1    A    151315    2 2010-02-05        46039
3:     2    A    152825    1 2010-02-05        41596
4:     2    A    152825    2 2010-02-05        19404
5:     3    B    110025    1 2010-02-05        21828
6:     3    B    110025    2 2010-02-05        21043
```

Ideally I want to create an array object which can store multiple matrix, on each matrix I want to have a single store. Basically I want to have on each level of the array the weekly sales on each department so I can run some time series analyses on the array object without running the same function multiple time.

This command will produce the kind of matrix I want for one layer of an array.

```
dcast(raw.df[which(raw.df$Store == 1), ], Date ~ Dept, value.var = "Weekly_Sales")
head(e1)
```

I was thinking to generate an empty array and fill it using a `for loop`. I wrote this loop, which unfortunately doesn't work. 
The dimension of the array are 143 (days), 99 (departments for each store), 45 (stores)

```
ts.a <- array(data = NA, dim = c(143, 99, 45))
for (i in 1:45) {
  # generate 45 matrices, one for each store
  paste("mat", i, sep = "") <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = 143, ncol = 99)
  paste("mat", i, sep = "") <- dcast(raw.df[which(raw.df$Store == i), ], Date ~ Dept, 
                                     value.var = "Weekly_Sales")

  # merge the matrix into the array object    
}
```

I realise my approach might be completely wrong. My knowlegde or R and programming are completely self-taught.

Comment: It is a little unclear to me why you seem to think that a three dimensional array will be the most efficient way to store this data. Can you elaborate on that a bit?

Comment: Rather than ask for a specific solution to your problem, why don't you tell us what your actual problem is?  `data.table` is quite versatile for this type of analysis (applying similar computations to multiple groups of data).

Comment: I agree with the previous comments and, also, see `?xtabs` as a future utility; e.g. `xtabs(Weekly_Sales ~ Date + Dept + Store, DF)`

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide easily usable data, I'll use the french_fries dataset shipped with reshape2:

```
str(french_fries)
acast(data=french_fries, time~treatment~subject, value.var='potato', fun.aggregate=mean)
```

Which gives an arrray of time vrs. treatment, with a slice for each subject.

So the equivalent with your data would be something like:

```
acast(data=raw_df, Date~Dept~Store, value.var='potato')
```

If you have multiple values for at least one Date~Dept~Store combination, you will have to provide a function to aggregate the data (the default is `length`, with a warning).

Answer (score 0):

What kind of analysis are you looking to do? You might be better off keeping the original data.frame and using `ddply` from the `plyr` package to perform operations by certain groups. I frequently use this for timeseries analysis across various subsets. Consider the following example,

```
dat<-data.frame(store=sample(1:3, 1000, T),
                type=sample(1:3, 1000, T),
                date=sample(1:100, 1000, T),
                val=rnorm(1000))
ddply(dat, .(store, type), # we can run a regression for our subgroups
      function(x){
        model<-lm(date ~ val, data=x)
        c(cf=coef(model), num=nrow(x), adjr2=summary(model)$adj.r.squared)
      })
```